# How to use quaternions to store the rotation of a camera?

Tags: c++, quaternions, glm-math

I'm trying to make a "6 degrees of freedom" camera like the ones used in space games. I would like to learn how to store camera rotation as a quaternion but I can't exactly find anything on the internet to help me (or maybe I don't know what keywords I should be using).

What I want to do is use a `glm::quat` to store the orientation of the camera but the parts that I'm having issues with is changing the pitch, yaw, roll and finding out how to get the new up, right and direction vectors needed for the `glm::lookAt` function to create a view matrix.

So far this is my code with the functions I need help with marked:

```cpp
#include "camera.hpp"
#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/quaternion.hpp>

Camera::Camera(glm::vec3 position, glm::quat orientation, float zNear, float zFar)
{
    this->position = position;
    this->orientation = orientation;

    right     = glm::vec3( 1,  0,  0);
    up        = glm::vec3( 0,  1,  0);
    direction = glm::vec3( 0,  0, -1);

    this->zNear = zNear;
    this->zFar = zFar;

    updateViewMatrix();
}

Camera::Camera(glm::vec3 position, glm::vec3 orientation, float zNear, float zFar)
{
    this->position = position;
    this->orientation = glm::quat(glm::vec3(glm::radians(orientation.x), glm::radians(orientation.y), glm::radians(orientation.z)));

    right     = glm::vec3( 1,  0,  0);
    up        = glm::vec3( 0,  1,  0);
    direction = glm::vec3( 0,  0, -1);

    this->zNear = zNear;
    this->zFar = zFar;

    updateViewMatrix();
}

void Camera::setPosition(glm::vec3 position)
{
    this->position = position;
}

void Camera::setOrientation(glm::quat orientation)
{
    this->orientation = orientation;
}

void Camera::setOrientation(glm::vec3 orientation)
{
    glm::quat orientationQuat = glm::quat(orientation);
    this->orientation = orientationQuat;
}

void Camera::setPitch(float amount)
{
    // NEED HELP
    updateViewMatrix();
}

void Camera::setYaw(float amount)
{
    // NEED HELP
    updateViewMatrix();
}

void Camera::setRoll(float amount)
{
    // NEED HELP
    updateViewMatrix();
}

void Camera::setZNear(float zNear)
{
    this->zNear = zNear;
    updateProjectionMatrix();
}

void Camera::setZFar(float zFar)
{
    this->zFar = zFar;
    updateProjectionMatrix();
}

void Camera::move(glm::vec3 movement)
{
    position += right * movement.x + up * movement.y + direction * movement.z;
    updateViewMatrix();
}

void Camera::moveAxis(glm::vec3 translation)
{
    position += translation;
    updateViewMatrix();
}

void Camera::rotate(glm::quat rotation)
{
    // NEED HELP
}

void Camera::rotate(glm::vec3 rotation)
{
    glm::quat rotationQuat = glm::quat(rotation);
    // NEED HELP
}

void Camera::pitch(float amount)
{
    // NEED HELP
    updateViewMatrix();
}

void Camera::yaw(float amount)
{
    // NEED HELP
    updateViewMatrix();
}

void Camera::roll(float amount)
{
    // NEED HELP
    updateViewMatrix();
}
// Excluded a few get___() functions here
glm::mat4 Camera::getViewMatrix() const
{
    return viewMatrix;
}
glm::mat4 Camera::getProjectionMatrix() const
{
    return projectionMatrix;
}
glm::mat4 Camera::getViewProjectionMatrix() const
{
    return viewProjectionMatrix;
}
void Camera::updateViewMatrix()
{
    viewMatrix = glm::lookAt(position, position + direction, up/*glm::cross(right, direction)*/);
    viewProjectionMatrix = projectionMatrix * viewMatrix;
}
```

These are the relevant variables I create in my header file:

```cpp
glm::vec3 position;
glm::quat orientation;
glm::vec3 direction; // Camera Direction / Camera View Facing
glm::vec3 right;
glm::vec3 up;
```

Comment: A quaternion is typically used to avoid the problems (gimbal lock) that are inherent in "pitch, yaw, roll".  If you want a quaternion, you probably don't want pitch, yaw, roll.  You want every individual rotation to be relevant to its current orientation.  And if you want pitch, yaw, roll, you probably don't want a quaternion.

Comment: Try to create a quaternion with the offset for each rotation, and apply this offset on top of the current quaternion (update it) that contains the orientation.

Comment: In my pitch function I made a quaternion that holds the pitch `glm::quat rotation = glm::angleAxis(glm::radians(amount), right);` and then added it to the orientation `orientation *= rotation;`
How do I change the right, up and direction vectors I use for the view matrix so the quaternion can be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to my problem of "How to find the right, up and direction vectors for the glm::lookat function"

All I need to do now is change the world up, right and direction vectors by the orientation of the quaternion like so:

```cpp
right = glm::normalize(orientation * glm::vec3(1, 0, 0));
up = glm::normalize(orientation * glm::vec3(0, 1, 0));
direction = glm::normalize(orientation * glm::vec3(0, 0, -1));
```